# Excel - Update Column with Date Time when Another Cell is First Changed

Tags: excel, vba

I would like my Excel spreadsheet Column B to be stamped with a date time only when Column A first changes.  I have seen a lot of VBA code but it captures the last change, not the first change.

I tried to use this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
    End If
End Sub
```

It worked except when I copy and paste into say 3 rows, the date time stamp only shows up for the first of 3 records.

Comment: What do you mean with 'first change' - every time after the workbook has been opened; always when B is empty;  ...?

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for me

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: That doesn't work if values already exist in column B and some values are pasted again, because the error-handling is disabled and it ignores the check for `Value = ""`.

Comment: @AndyG If the values exist in column B it mean the corresponding Value in Column A is already edited.

Answer (score -1):

I receive an error message when attempting to paste into several cells of column A, from this line:

```
Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
```

This is because the Offset is a Range of more than one cell, and we can't compare the `Value` of this Range to an individual value.

You can check `Target.Rows.Count`. If this is greater than 1 then you can loop through the `Target` Range, each time checking if the adjacent cell is empty before entering a value into `Offset(0, 1)`.

The following loops through the `Target` cells, and works even if the Target is a single cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rng In Target
            If rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
                rng.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "HH:MM:SS")
            End If
        Next rng
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

You should also check if `Target` extends beyond a single column. If it does, then presumably you only want to enter the stamp into column B (for a change in column A).